# Fetch plain json from mongo in go

Tags: json, mongodb, go, mgo

I am trying to fetch some data from `mongo` in `go` and using `gopkg.in/mgo.v2`. I have a nested data in mongo.

*Note: This is an old database I cannot change structure for and just want to query the data.*

I have a database with fields `id`, `name` and `details`. and I have to get details based on `id`
My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type Person struct {
    Name string
    Id string
    Details string
}


func main() {

    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://localhost:27017/naren")

    c := session.DB("naren").C("people")

    result := Person{}
    err = c.Find(bson.M{"id": "12345"}).One(&result)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Details:", result.Details)
    fmt.Println("Name:", result.Name)
    fmt.Println("Id:", result.Id)
}
```

`Id` and `Name` are printing fine but `result.Details` prints an empty string even when there is data. I just want to print json as string or am happy with a json data.

I have also tried

```
...
type Person struct { 
    ...
    Details string `json:"details"`
}
```

But still get empty string. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm you have data in details field?

Comment: Also ask question with actual code segment what you have used in your program. `fmt.Println("Name:", result.name)` This should not print name.

Comment: @aerokite yes I can confirm details has value and result.Name does print name

Comment: What is the result if you change the type of `Details` from `string` to `interface{}`? Or, try change it to `bson.M`?

Comment: @putu and it seems to be working. I get data with either and gives something like  map[hobbies:running]. I need to turn this to JSON. Thanks for the help. I am new to go, and seems hard.

Comment: It seems like your `Details` is not a `string` instead a json object, which you will have to map to a appropriate `struct`. Can you show sample data for `Details` field from mongo?

Comment: @developernaren  i guess  the data Details is storing is not type of string . Could you share the sample data for Details .So that will get the clear picture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am very new to go. This seems very basic now. The value of key `details` was `JSON`

The fix was that I changed the type of details to `bson.M`

from

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Id string
    Details string
}
```

to

```
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Id string
    Details bson.M
}
```

now I can access the details like

```
res, err := json.Marshal(result.Details)

fmt.Println(string(res))
```

Thanks @putu for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: After trying many attempts, this one really works. No need string(res), just write res

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the field is an embedded document (maybe a JSON object or a JSON array). I have to set the field type to `bson.RawValue`:

```golang
type Person struct {
    Name string
    Id string
    Details bson.RawValue
}
```

and then check whether Details is an object or an array using if-else:

```golang
var d interface{}

var m bson.M
var a bson.A

e := person.Details.Unmarshal(&m)
d = m

if e != nil {
        _ = person.Details.Unmarshal(&a)
        d = a
}
```

After unmarshal, `d` will be a `bson.M` or `bson.A`.

---

*Side note*: `bson.M{}` objects will default be decoded to `{Key: realKey, Value: realValue}`, if you want `{realKey: realValue}` structure, unmarshal with a custom registry:

```golang
rb := bson.NewRegistryBuilder()
rb.RegisterTypeMapEntry(bsontype.EmbeddedDocument, reflect.TypeOf(bson.M{}))
reg := rb.Build()

var d interface{}

var m bson.M
var a bson.A

e := object.Data.UnmarshalWithRegistry(reg, &m)
d = m

if e != nil {
        _ = object.Data.UnmarshalWithRegistry(reg, &a)
        d = a
}
```